# "User is not set" IncompleteDsnException after migrating to Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, symphony-cms, laravel-9

I was using Laravel 8.64, and my emails were working fine both on prod and dev servers. However, after upgrading to 9.0.2, I have an issue with sending emails. Of course, I followed all instructions, but still, I get errors when I try to send an email.

> User is not set. {"exception":"[object]
> (Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\IncompleteDsnException(code:
> 0): User is not set.

After some reasearch in vendor folder i found class `AbstractTransportFactory` that contains `getUser` method.

```
protected function getUser(Dsn $dsn): string
{
    $user = $dsn->getUser();
    if (null === $user) {
        throw new IncompleteDsnException('User is not set.');
    }

    return $user;
}
```

When I `return '';` in this if statement, everything is working fine instead of throwing an exception. Does anyone know the solution for this and why this is happening

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same issue.

Make sure that your .env file contains:
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=your.domain.com
MAILGUN_SECRET=your.mailgun.secret

This would be reflected as the username/password for the DSN.

Cheers

Comment: Thats solution! Thank you very much. But where did you find it? I could not find env() check for those anywhere since i have them setup in mail.php

Comment: I didn't find it as well, so I started tracking down the flow until I found where it was pulling the user, and I realized it was looking for those details.

Comment: Found it in docs here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail#driver-prerequisites

Comment: I have the same issue as the OP with POSTMARK. Any suggestion fo rthis?=

Comment: @Adam I was seeing the same issue in my application when I ran my unit tests.  I did some logging in the vendor file AbstractTransportFactory.php and it turns out that my unit tests end up losing the env('POSTMARK_TOKEN') environment variable after the first time the environment variable is read.

Check out: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/36164, you should change env('POSTMARK_TOKEN') to getenv('POSTMARK_TOKEN') and I think your issues will be resolved.